# Различия между 2 способами инициализации строковой переменной

Tags: java

Существует ли разница между инициализацией переменной text 1 cпособом и 2-ым?

1)`String text = "Hello";`

2)`String text = new String("Hello");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, существуют.

При первом способе (`String text = "Hello"`) , если строчка `"Hello"` уже есть в [пуле констант](https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool), то значение возьмется оттуда. Если такой строчки в пуле нет, то при таком создании она автоматически добавится в пул.

При втором способе (`String text = new String("Hello")`) будет явно создаваться новая ссылка, не смотря на пул констант. Чтобы явно положить строку в пул при таком создании, используется метод [intern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--)

Обычно, используют 1 вариант, чтобы лишний раз не засорять память.

**P.S.** если уж совсем придираться, то при `String text = new String("Hello")` сначала строчка `Hello` возьмется ( если есть) из пула констант, потом уже создаться новая ссылка на `text`. И вывод `text == "Hello"` будет `false`